# Why do many governments incentivize / subsidize (personal) home ownership?

Tags: subsidies, housing

In many countries, **home ownership** (meaning owning one's primary residence, instead of living in rented accomodation) is subsidized or otherwise incentivized or supported by the government.

For example (not an exhaustive list, obviously):

- in Germany there used to be a subsidy for buying/building a self-occupied home ([Baukindergeld](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baukindergeld))
- in the USA, there are special tax advantages for home mortgages ([Home mortgage interest deduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Home_mortgage_interest_deduction))
- in France, there is a tax-free loan ([Prêt à taux zéro (PTZ)](https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/F10871)) offered for buying a self-occupied home
- in Singapore, the government-run Housing & Development Board [provides grants for buying a family home](https://www.hdb.gov.sg/about-us/news-and-publications/publications/hdbspeaks/more-grants-for-firsttimers-buying-resale-flats)

Why do these countries provide this special support? I can see a good argument for making sure everyone has adequate housing available, but why provide special support for owning instead of renting? I would have assumed support to be based on the individual housing need, not on the ownership of accomodation.

I am particularly interested in published justification, but other considerations/theories  would be interesting as well.

Comment: The German Baukindergeld is not so much intended to subsidize the home, but to subsidizing starting a family (on the assumption that the middle class is more likely to have kids if they do not need to chose between being able to afford either a home or children).

Comment: Don't forget the subsidy of not taxing imputed rent. See: https://www.vox.com/2016/4/15/11432676/imputed-rent-taxation , https://www.businessinsider.com/imputed-rent-hidden-tax-break-homeowners-2016-9 , https://www.taxpolicycenter.org/sites/default/files/briefing-book/4.8.1_what_are_the_tax_benefits-from-home-ownership.pdf

Comment: One tax advantage in the USA is more theoretical than actual.   Most taxpayers will take the standard deduction rather than itemizing their mortgage interest.

Comment: While that tax advantage does not effectively exist for the whole life of the loan, When I purchased my house, for about the first 2/3 of the mortgage period, the interest was sufficient to make itemizing worth wile. And I had a fairly low interest rate.

Comment: In Germany, you get many more fiscal advantages if you rent a flat you bought than if you live in it. I guess many lawmakers bought flats and rented them, so why not make it easier for themselves?

Comment: Another example is Denmark: There isn't any tax on capital gains buying/selling a house you live in (unlike, say, United States). 0%. The interest is also (partially) deductable.

Answer (score 22):

Different reasoning in different societies. Among them:

- House ownership is far from the only government subsidy affecting necessities. In [germany](/questions/tagged/germany), there is are reduced VAT rate for food, rent paid by welfare offices, etc.
- Retirement savings are often subsidized. Often home ownership is a way of retirement saving (take a loan, pay it off over a working live, own it clear in old age).
- The upper middle classes, who are able to afford home ownership *with* a subsidy but possibly not without it, are better able to organize their political interest than lower classes. So the political system co-opts them by subsidizing their goal.

Comment: I wonder where do you live so that *upper* middle class can only afford home ownership with a subsidy - Singapore?

Comment: @alamar even if the upper middle class can go by without that subsidy... why reject it if they can get it? That way they spend less or get a better home at someone else's expense.

Comment: This answer does not explain why a govt that takes from everybody to give to the middle class, especially the upper middle class, manages to stay in power by doing exactly that.

Comment: @alamar, Germany. Have you looked at housing costs there lately?

Comment: @BobaFit, because the middle class is more likely to organize for effective political action than the lower class. My third bullet point. The government does what the voters want, and guess who *does* and who *doesn't* go to vote? https://de.statista.com/statistik/daten/studie/1258127/umfrage/wahlbeteiligung-der-sozialen-milieus-bei-der-bundestagswahl/

Comment: @alamar House in the San Francisco bay area have been priced out of the reach of most middle-class families.

Comment: @o.m.: Home ownership in Germany is about 50%? Unless you have a particularly unusual definition of middle class, that 50% can only be achieved if a significant fraction of the middle class are home owners. (There will be people in the upper and middle class who rent for convenience, not by necessity. Think expats)

Comment: @alamar it's very common in the pricier areas of the US and Canada for the upper middle class to struggle to afford a home, {even with} the subsidies. I've got an old college friend in Vancouver, newly minted specialist doctor, makes >C$300K/y(in the 1% in Can), he can't even afford a starter apartment on what's left after taxes and med school debt. Here in Seattle, I have colleagues in tech who are married and make >$500k/y together who are delaying kids, because the daycare costs on top of their mortgage would be too much. Same in SF, NY, LA, Toronto, San Diego, etc. even Austin these days.

Comment: @MSalters Those 50% are made up to a large part by those who built houses between 1950 and 1990 (and their heirs), when I would agree this was still affordable for average incomes. Since then, the real estate market has become much more difficult, and deregulation of working laws meant that people no longer had a good chance to hold on to their job for life. Thus paying off a 20-years mortgage, even if interest rates have been extraordinarily low for the last 15 years, is much more of a risk than it was in earlier decades.

Comment: @o.m. It's not _that_ bad;.  I'd say [€80k for 70 m²](https://www.immobilienscout24.de/expose/135962616) is achievable for regular middle class, not only for upper middle class. OK, it's in Eisenhüttenstadt (formerly known as Stalinstadt), but a nurse or a teacher can probably find a job there and buy an €80k apartment.  I moved from southern England to the Rhein-Main area and housing prices per m² are about half here, and [even cheaper](https://www.immobilienscout24.de/expose/137466714) if one accepts a somewhat longer commute (but I don't know if €200k is still middle class).

Comment: @gerrit, agreed for places like that. And with the rise in home office, the trend might even reverse. But in a major city?

Comment: In the netherlands this has been teh case since.. forever? You need about 2.5-3 times average wage to afford a simple 5 room apartment.

Answer (score 21):

In the US, it simply crept in. When the federal income tax on businesses and individuals was created in 1913, it was only natural to treat interest payments paid by businesses on loans to those businesses as business expenses. This was carried forward to interest payments on a mortgage as a deductible living expense.

The initial intent was not to subsidize mass home ownership as initially only the wealthiest Americans were subject to personal income taxes. It wasn't until the mid to late 1930s that the majority of people were made to pay income taxes. The mortgage interest deduction was of course extended to those middle class taxpayers. The 1944 Servicemen's Readjustment Act (aka the GI Bill) explicitly did subsidize home ownership by returning veterans in the form of low cost loans and a mortgage interest deduction that countered the extremely high post WWII tax rates.

The mortgage interest deduction has been changed only one time, and it snuck in as a provision in the 1987 Omnibus Budget Reconciliation Act that caps the mortgage interest deduction at one million dollars per year. (Some call this the "immaculate conception provision" because no one knows the source of this provision.) Ronald Reagan later proposed making the cap even lower, at half a million dollars. The real estate lobby was "deeply disappointed." Reagan's proposed reduction did not make it into law.

If you think the gun or pharmaceutical lobbies are powerful, think again. There are multiple very powerful lobbies (e.g., real estate, home construction, and home repair lobbies) that strongly defend the mortgage interest deduction and other aspects of federal tax law that benefit homeowners. In addition to those vested lobbies, homeowners vote disproportionately compared to renters. It's been estimated that home prices would drop by about 15% should the mortgage interest deduction be removed.

Comment: Note that interest on *all* loans used to be tax-deductible.  The Tax Reform Act of 1986 changed this, but the *mortgage* interest deduction was kept because it was politically infeasible to remove it.

Comment: *It's been estimated that home prices would drop by about 15% should the mortgage interest deduction be removed* => interesting, would you mind adding the source if you remember it? Not that I doubt it's possible but would be curious to see the numbers.

Comment: Is there a way to tell what percentage of homeowners with mortgages actually itemize their taxes?   Don't most people (in low to mid income ranges) just take the standard deduction?

Comment: @MichaelRichardson A $350K mortgage for a house is fairly common. (There are many areas in the country where that would be a rundown starter house.) That might result in about $25K in interest payments, at least at first. While that's not quite the standard deduction for a married couple, it does open the door to lots of other deductions. If the mortgage interest was not deductible (or if ones mortgage is fully paid off), those other deductions typically don't come close to matching the standard deduction.

Comment: @MichaelRichardson For 2010-2021, absolutely. Prior to that a 10% mortgage wouldn't have been unheard of. I suspect the study David is referring to does not apply to 2-3% interest rates where the standard deduction is indeed much more appealing to most.

Comment: "The mortgage interest deduction has been changed only one time" - Didn't the 2017 Tax Cuts and Jobs Act (TCJA) change this again to cap the loan limit to $750,000? Also, I struggle to understand why the real estate lobby would be "deeply disappointed" if a reduction did not make it into law.

Comment: @JonathanReez 2-3% interest rates are a thing of the past.

Comment: @GlenYates The real estate lobby was "deeply disappointed" that the reduction was even proposed, and then they fought it tooth and nail.

Comment: @GlenYates: yes TCJA reduced the principal limit to 750k (half if MFS), although loans before Dec 16 2017 were grandfathered. TCJA also restricted the deduction to loans _for_ construction, purchase or improvement of the home (no more using home equity for a subsidized vacation in the Bahamas) (_not_ grandfathered). And it reduced or eliminated some other itemized deductions while increasing the standard deduction, making itemizing beneficial for significantly fewer taxpayers (IRS figures show itemizing fell from about 30% to about 10%).

Comment: @JonathanReez I'd say that it's a relatively straightforward consequence of the fact that home prices are effectively set by how much mortgage people can get, and any market-scale changes to mortgage conditions mean that after the short-term fluctuations settle down, the average monthly mortgage payment is essentially the same (the max of what people can afford and lenders are willing to give) but home prices adjust to meet that. So the expected long-term effect of some tax on mortgage payments is that people are able to pay smaller payments, and thus house prices shrink.

Comment: If you’re truly confident 2-3% rates are never coming back there’s financial instruments that will make you a lot of money if you’re right ;-)

Answer (score 20):

Whenever a question of the form "Why do governments do this?" we need to "round up the usual suspects."

- They think it will extend their time in power or increase their control or extend their influence.
- They think they can make money for themselves or their friends, relatives, associates, etc.
- They think they can wield it as a weapon against their enemies.
- They think they can use it to trade favors with people they want to influence or reward.

There are lots of obvious ways that these apply to housing.

- There is a lot of money involved in houses. If, in the USA, six million families [buy a house in a year](https://www.statista.com/statistics/226144/us-existing-home-sales/) this is getting into the range of $Trillion.
- The six million families have corresponding numbers of people who vote. Both family members who live in the houses, and their friends and relatives who are glad for them
- There are large numbers of jobs involved in building and renovating houses. These people vote.
- Houses involve mortgages which in turn involve banking and accounting regulations and tax law. Pushing housing allows the politicians to get leverage over these other aspects and industries.

The harm that subsidies may do is pushed into the distant future, and hidden by layers of action. For example, if the mortgage market is distorted by subsidies, the increase in interest rates and bankruptcies may not happen for years. And it may be  possible to obscure the connection. Until the result is the sub-prime crisis of 2007-2008.

So increasing housing gets them votes from trades workers. And favors from cities that get to increase property tax on houses. And loss of the subsidies can be held as a threat against people who might try to oust the politicians who could remove the subsidy.

A distorted housing market screws up the banking industry. Which is good for politicians because now they can recycle the whole process to "rescue" the banks.

These are examples of principles that are at work. The fact that they work the way the politicians like is evidenced by the fact they keep doing them. The fact that they *don't* work they way they *say* they are intended is evidenced by the fact that the housing market in subsidized locations is distorted beyond all recognition. Again, recall the 2007-2008 sub-prime crisis.

Comment: I said $1 Trillion. https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/ASPUS  It's pushing $3 Trillion.  In the last two years the average sale price of houses in the US has risen by about 40%.  This is kind of alarming.

Comment: Alarming as in: end of the USD as we know it. Collapse of the global economy. We all starve to death as nobody can agree to allocate fertilizer and food. Well, that's just one possible outcome. A different possibility is everyone who bought a house in the last two years becomes 60% poorer, and everyone who didn't carries on.

Comment: Cynically, there's also the factor that right-wing governments often seek to destroy anything state-funded, such as state-owned or social housing, and encouraging home ownership may go alongside that. The attack is either explicit, as when the British government in the 1980s sold off state-owned homes to tenants, or implicitly, so they can cut social housing but point to relief for home-owners as an alternative way of helping people have housing.

Comment: @StuartF So a government that tries to decrease its net size is "cynical." OK then.

Answer (score 19):

Other answers have addressed the economic and political aspects of why a government may incentivize homeownership. However, there are sociological reasons as well. These stem from the idea that one of the primary purposes of government is to ensure social stability.

One example of this is the [institution of marriage](https://www.baltimoresun.com/opinion/bs-xpm-2011-02-03-bs-ed-purpose-of-marriage-letter-20110203-story.html). The theory goes, by making possibly restless young people focused on domestic life, they're less likely to commit crime, join revolts, cause trouble etc. And on the positive side, having stable emotional relations with another person is likely to improve their psychological state. Part and parcel with this is the concept of the *household*. If the government thinks marriage will improve stability, and having houses for married couples improves their stability further, it makes sense for the government to incentivize home buying.

Ok, but why would having a house be a stabilizing effect on someone's life? [Here are a few possible reasons](https://habitatlcnc.org/16-news/100-beneficial-impacts-of-homeownership-a-research-summary) and their [references](https://habitatlcnc.org/blog-hidden/101-references):

- Less risk of being unhoused: Once the mortgage is payed off, the home is owned. If the person gets laid off, they don't need to worry about affording rent.
- Less financial risk: The home itself can appreciate in value and also provide collateral for loans in situations that might otherwise be financially ruinous.
- Less health risk. More communal house may be of poorer quality, impacting health outcomes. While this might not be as large of a factor now, consider the situation in the early-mid 1900s where urban rental stock was probably from the 1800s, ie without modern construction and health regulations.
- Greater educational attainment (possibly US specific reason): Schools are largely funded locally and you can typically only send your child to public schools in your district. Once initial affluent single family home communities are established, the public schools systems in those communities were better than their rural or city counterparts. This leads to better eduction outcomes for any children a person might have. Obviously, a person renting could still send their child to a school in the same community if they were geographically close, but having a home *ensures* your child will stay there.
- Greater community building. Simply knowing your neighbor, and knowing that they will be there for a while changes how you interact with them. There's no reason a rental building, or person living in rental units can't also have a sense of community, but its more likely that people will move in these situations, which makes it harder to form lasting bonds.

Finally, since you were looking for publications, one further link I'll provide is [this study](https://www.gmar.com/data/resources_files/Social%20Benefits%20of%20Homeownership%20%20Stable%20Housing.pdf) conducted by the National Association of Realtor's Research division. It goes through many of the reasons described above, and adds others.

*Caveat! All the sources I have used have their own bias. Habitat for humanity and the Association of Realtors obviously have their own reasons for wanting houses to seem good.

Comment: "ensure social stability".  This was exactly my first thought.  It's great to stimulate the economy, but not too many people rebel if it means their own property gets trashed.

Comment: @RonJohn or even if their debt load goes down! I think that's the real reason for mortgages: it means that anyone who dares to defy the system gets punished very severely.

Comment: @user253751 I really don’t think the first companies issuing mortgages were thinking about social stability.

Comment: @RonJohn No, the individual mortgage issuer isn't, but like many things in our society, the system is much bigger than any individual actor within it.

Comment: @user253751 there is no Deep State “real reason” conspiracy.  “They” are just **taking advantage of the situation**.

Comment: @RonJohn the situation exists because of people

Comment: There are of course other ways of ensuring stable housing, such as long-term tenancies (some countries like the UK formerly offered life-long tenancies in state-owned housing), or restrictions on landlords' activity. But these carry both cost to the state (building, running houses) and infringe on the activities of landlords who by their nature are often wealthy and politically active.

Answer (score 7):

I live in Norway, where owning your own apartment or house, is almost seen as a universal right, and there are very strong tax incentives. Renting an apartment or house is very rare. Most people in Norway spend a lot of time indoors, especially during winter.

I believe the most important arguments for incentivising people to own their own house or apartment are:

1. You do not need to ask for permission for modifying your house or apartment, as long as it's within building codes. This includes any modifications you yourself need or want, even if it would reduce the sales value of the property.
2. There isn't any need to fight the landlord to get him/her to fix broken things, paint, or do cosmetic changes. You can simply do so yourself whenever you want, or when you can afford it.
3. Any improvements you do will benefit yourself, and not the landlord. If you do improvements, you get a higher price when/if you sell.
4. Being able to do modifications without asking for anyone's permission, means you don't have to move to another house or apartment as often as if you couldn't change it.
5. When you pay your mortgage, you are saving for yourself. When you pay rent, you save money for the landlord.

The first four arguments are mostly about quality of life for individuals and families. But having properties properly taken care of by interested owners, will obviously be positive for the society at large too.

The fifth argument is the most commonly cited argument by Norwegians, but probably mostly makes sense from an insider perspective, where the incentives already are in place. I do not think it is a particularly good argument for changing government policy (but I do believe the first four are).

Comment: This are arguments for a *person* to become an owner, but doesn’t answer why a *government* should *incentivize* such ownership.

Comment: I am not trying to convince a dictator about the benefits of home ownership. In a democracy, the government should represent the will of the people. If something is good for individuals, the government ought to support it, unless there are good reasons not to.

Comment: *You do not need to ask for permission for modifying your house or apartment* - there are no HOAs in Norway?

Comment: "owning your own apartment or house, is almost seen as a universal right".  At what age are people expected to own homes?  (I can't see many people doing so straight out of college.

Comment: Mortgaging an apartment should not be that hard out of college, especially if parents help you with down payment - that's how it works in Russia which also has huge % of home ownership.

Comment: @JonathanReez homeowner associations that govern whole areas of multiple homes are very unusual outside of the United States. Usually a HOA only governs a single multi-tenant apartment building.

Comment: @Philipp right but they’re still managing apartments in Norway I presume? And if you’re in an HOA you’re effectively not a *true* “home owner”

Comment: @alamar mortgaging, perhaps, but it's not truly yours until the mortgage is paid off.

Comment: The transaction costs are also very high, 5% - 20% of the property's value, so you are *effectively* stuck in the same place for at least 10 years. (For example, what if the neighbours are naturally *noisy*?)

Comment: "When you pay your mortgage, you are saving for yourself. When you pay rent, you save money for the landlord" - This is a widely held myth that I won't attempt to debunk in the space of a comment.

Comment: @Nayuki whether or not it’s a myth depends entirely on whether or not one’s interest payments are higher or lower than one’s rent. It’s not a myth, it just depends.

Comment: Norway doesn't typically have HOA in the american sense. Our HOAs exists for common infrastructure, like roads, playgrounds, etc.. But you need to abide by law and local regulations, which in many cases means you need approval from neighbors for building extensions. If you live in an apartment, the exterior of the building is typically under strong rules by HOA, but you can do what you want indoors. There is a 2.5% tax on selling your house. The rental market exists mostly for young people without sufficent savings, poor people, or short-term workers.

Comment: Norwegians typically move out of their parents home early, typically at 18-20 years. Because the housing market has mostly gone up the latest decades, buying a home is perceived by most as a good and safe investment. Getting help from parents is common. If you do not get help from your parents, you need to save money. There are special tax incentives for saving for your first home. But it can still be very hard.

Answer (score 6):

One special case is Russia, where over 70% people own their homes.

Everybody knows that in early 90s, Russia was basically stolen by thugs who privatized state enterprises via opaque and corrupt process.

Not everybody knows, however, that in the same 90s, Russia also privatized state-owned homes (apartments especially) - the one apartment that you have, de jure, rented from the state at the end of Soviet period, you could now own, just by submitting some paperwork. Then you could sell it, rent it out, etcetra.

So in this case, apparently, personal home ownership can be viewed as a sort of agreement between the government and the masses - the government gets to decide what to do with means of production by giving homes for the masses to own.

Curiously, some research pieces which claim very high wealth inequality in Russia exclude the homes owned by Russian citizens from the equation. Obviously, most of the wealth owned by most of the people is their home(s), usually in the form of apartments.

Comment: Countries that were never Communist also exhibit this phenomenon, such as the USA.

Answer (score 2):

Purely from an economical perspective:

- House ownership is a form of **retirement saving**: people are more willing to put aside money in a house loan than on a long-term investment account, so let's promote this way of saving.
- House ownership incentivizes people to **improve their standard of living**, i.e., by renovating, insulating, repairing the house. A home owner who rents out the house has little motivation to make the house energy-efficient, as the heating costs are for the renter. The renter on the other hand knows he can be evicted, so an expensive renovation that yields benefit only in the long run is risky. Owning your own house solves this, and benefits society as well (e.g., less dependence on polluting foreign fossil fuels).

Answer (score 2):

Things that were not mentioned, but IMO worth adding:

- Renting is business. At the end of the day landlord is in for
  revenue, thus "renting is cheaper" is not true in general, and
  especially if you factor in the fact that after mortgage is payed out
  you are left with the asset. Government subsidizing ownership is
  making sure "richer" don`t get to make income from poorer, and family
  home is the inheritance children get, which is also significant.
- Land    lords have no incentive to compete on price, thus making
  ownership    another option is creation of that competition, or
  making it    stronger.
- Land lords don`t have much incentive to sell    their    property,
  nor to buy more, packing people more for more rent    revenue
  would be their preference, which is bad for almost    everyone, but
  building industry especially.
- Here is the funny    part, land lords are    interested in high
  ownership rate. Local goverments and even countries also are.
  The reason is, this    reduces mobility. People are    less likely to
  move or migrate if    they own their home, which reduces
  possibility that local    communities become deserted, if economic
  downturn starts.    Obviously land lords don`t want their expensive
  property to become    useless due to large outflow from a particular
  location, so is    local government.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow most of your arguments here.

Comment: The last one is a killer one, in Russia you can charge close to median wage for a decent rent-out flat, since most of the workforce owns their apartments and don't have to rent at market rate. You can live off of one property if you are a retired landlord.

Comment: While these points may or may not be true, I don't see how this answers the Q. The question was why there is government support for owning a home, not what the problems are with renting.

Answer (score 0):

I'll add two points to all the other good answers here: **political goodwill** and **tax revenue**.

Everybody wants to own a home one day. A government policy supporting this desire obviously earns the goodwill of such voters.

> ... but why provide special support for owning instead of renting?

To increase tax revenue - home owners in most countries pay some form **property tax** that contributes to a local government's budget, and the more property owners there are, the more tax the local government body earns. Also, note that you need homes in the first place to rent it out. So government policies that incentivise building new homes theoretically also help by preventing rents from rising, resulting in cheaper accommodation.

Comment: "To increase tax revenue... property tax" - I cannot follow here. No matter whether people own or rent, *someone* will own the home, and pay tax, so I do not see how owner-occupied homes would make a difference.

Comment: @sleske If the government offers you assistance to rent a house, only the rent-owner pays the property tax. If the government helps you own your own house, now the government has two sources of tax revenue - you and your former rent-owner.